# Cypress: Unable to interact with page element

Tags: typescript, cypress

I’m attempting to identify whether or not a field is read only. When the element is in a read only state, the html code looks like this:

```
<textarea _ngcontent-njf-c545="" rows="1" cdktextareaautosize="" aria-label="Product name" matinput="" type="text" placeholder="'Enter a product name...'" required="" formcontrolname="productName" class="cdk-textarea-autosize mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c98-55 ng-untouched ng-pristine cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" ng-reflect-enabled="" ng-reflect-type="text" ng-reflect-placeholder="'Enter a product name...'" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="productName" id="mat-input-3" data-placeholder="'Enter a product name...'" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" disabled="" style="height: 21px;">              </textarea>
```

The field in question is the product name field:

[image]

We can see that our element has a ‘disabled’ attribute which exist only when the field is disabled, for my test I wanted to identify whether or not the disabled attribute existed within my element, if it does then I could assume that the element would be disabled and if it doesn’t then the field would be enabled

If I use the following code, I can select the field and successfully identify whether or not its read only or not

```
cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').should('be.disabled);
```

So although the above code works then the field is disabled, the code will break and throw an error if the field isn’t disabled
So to get around and from the examples ive seen, when we are performing at test like this we need to use the .then() function with a conditional If statement
The below code selects the element on the page containing `[formcontrolname="productName"]`, which is our product name field and passes it into our If statement so we can work with it, the script then attempts to identify if the ‘disabled’ text exists within the element
It doesn’t work and although the field is disabled I cant find the ‘disabled’ text within the element

```
cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').then((productName) => {
if (productName.find('disabled').length > 0) {
        cy.log('Field is disabled');
      } else {
        // do nothing
        cy.log('Field isn’t disabled');
      }
    });
```

So although this code successfully identifies if the field is read only or not I cant use it as the test will break if the field isn’t disabled

```
  cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').should('be.disabled);
```

But as soon as I use the .then() and pass in the field as a parameter for some reason I just cant interact in any way with the element
I’ve tried quite a few other ways

has.class disabled

.shoud(be.disabled) – thows an error

Has.attri, disabled

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:disabled` jquery method for this:

```js
cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.is(":disabled")) {
    cy.log("Field is disabled");
  } else {
    // do nothing
    cy.log("Field isn’t disabled");
  }
});
```

You can also use `.attr()` to check whether the element contains the disabled attribute with empty string as the value.

```js
cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.attr("disabled") == "") {
    cy.log("Field is disabled");
  } else {
    // do nothing
    cy.log("Field isn’t disabled");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i ended up using your first example which worked perfectly :)